# mongodb - strategy to ensure save data in different collections like a transaction at application level

Tags: mongodb, transactions, php-mongodb

I work with mongodb and I thing a possible strategy to save data in different collections, for example 2 collections. But, like a transactional system, I want ensure that data is present in collection1 and in collection2 or nothing.

In practicaly I want track operations that are performed into my application when execute something. So for example when my application save a data, I want also save that it has performed a insert operations, when modify data, I want track modify operation etc.

These operations data could save as embended document of single collection. For example if I  try save data into **collection1** then I can save "insert operation data" in same collection1 as embended document. If I try modify data into **collection2** then I can save "modify operation data" in same collection2 as embended document, and so on...
Thus when I want retrieve "operations embended document data" I must query collection1, collection2, collection3 etc etc.
I think that is expensive. Further collection1, collection2, collection3 are already stressed by application, so I don't want stress furthermore.

Alternative, I can save "operation data" in separate collection, for example "oper_coll" collection name. So I can query only "oper_coll" for retrieve "operations data" but it implies that when I save data in collection1 I must save "operation data" in "oper_coll" for tracking current operation. I want data is saved correctly in collection1 and operation in oper_coll. If something goes wrong it do nothing, data doesn't present in either collection ( collection1 and oper_coll ). So I need a something as transactional system at application level because I know that mongodb doesn't support transactions.

So I want implement something similar at application level, because I need save data1 into collection1 and if it is ok, it save data2 into collection2. If something goes wrong rollback all.

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

First I think this link would help, it provides an example of how to orchestrate a 2 phase commit using mongo.

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/

Based on the example in the link and some additional reading around the subject I've created a mongo style transaction using the unit of work design pattern.

Does that help at all?

Comment: How did you get on? I wrote the transaction data to a transaction collection along with id, date time, status etc. using the 2pc technique you can then process the transaction and manually process the rollback should anything fail along the way.  You can also retry the transaction as you have it written to the database as pending.  In mongo you can atomically update a single document.